# Analytical evaluation of a double integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions, multiple-integral

In a mathematical-physical problem, the following double integral has to be determined:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty qk \, \exp \left( ikq \right) \,
J_0 \left( k \sqrt{1-q^2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}k \, \mathrm{d}q \, ,
$$
which follows from an inverse Fourier transformation. 
A numerical integration of this double integral yields finite values.
However, when proceeding analytically, it can be shown that the integral over $k$ is divergent. 
I was wondering whether an analytical evaluation of this double integral is amenable. Your help and hints are most welcome.

Thanks

HH

Comment: What you said makes no sense.  Either the integral is divergent,, or it is not.  I think it is.  In that case, no numerical analysis will make it finite.

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks. What I mean is that integrating first over $k$ leads to divergence. Taking the integral as a whole with both variables is in principle convergent

Comment: Could you explain to me how that works?  Sorry, it just contradicts everything I know about math.

Comment: @RonGordon What I mean is: the integral $\int_0^\infty k e^{bk}J_0(ak)\, \mathrm{d}k$ is divergent if $a$ and $b$ are both reals. The double integral on the other hand, being a physical quantity, is and should be finite. You can check numerically that the double integral is convergent. I would like to know whether the final result can nicely be expressed in a simpler form, thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456291/prove-an-integral-involving-the-bessel-function